# после открытия клавиатуры, экран сдвигается в 2 раза больше чем занимает клавиатура на capacitor андроид

Tags: android, клавиатура, cordova

Я разрабатываю приложение для Android на Capacitor. Столкнулся с проблемой, что свойство тега `windowSoftInputMode`, равное `adjustPan`, сужает область видимости экрана в 2 раза больше, чем нужно для отображения клавиатуры. Если я устанавливаю adjustNothing, то события плагина клавиатуры, отслеживающие ее запуск и закрытие, не работают (особенность капаситора на андроиде, как я понял). Кажется, что это очень простой баг, но я пытаюсь решить его уже несколько дней.

[image: Скрин с проблемой]

Как видно, клавиатура занимает примерно треть экрана, неизвестная серая область еще треть, а дальше уже идет контент

В инспекторе это выглядит как то так

[image: скрин с инпектора]

Как будто экран сужается на 2/3 экрана

В свойстве `android:windowSoftInputMode` перебирал почти все возможные вариации.

В общем идеальным решением будет - как убрать эту серую зону, чуть менее идеальным, как заставить работать ивенты клавиатуры при
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`